# How to create a button in the controller which opens the form (ext js)

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications

I have a view (Main.js), form (RenterData.js) and I want to code controller which will open RenterData form by button from view Main.

Now my controller looks like that:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ButtonController', {

extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',



views: ['MyApp.view.main.Main'],

refs: [{
    ref: 'control-panel',
    selector: 'control-panel'
}],

init: function(application) {

    this.control({
        "RenterId": function () {
             click: this.onButtonClickRenterId  
        }
    })
},

onButtonClickRenterId: function() {
    /* place for form calling by button function */
}
```

});

I am a beginner in sencha ext js, and I don't understand which method I have to use for calling form by button. Note, that the button is into a carousel, which is into a menu on the view.
I use Ext JS 6.2.0

Grazie!

Comment: Did you consider defining your form in your view and hiding it by default? When the button is clicked you can simply display it with Ext.form.Panel.setVisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by showing the form content in a window or you can render it to a region panel in your view port here is an Example [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m9b)

app.js

```
Ext.application({
 name: 'Test',
 requires: ['Test.view.Main', 'Test.view.MyForm'],
 mainView: 'Test.view.Main',
 launch: function () {}
});
```

app/view/Main.js

```
Ext.define('Test.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
title: 'main',
xtype: 'main',
// renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
width: 600,
height: 400,
layout: 'border',
items: [{
    region: 'north',
    height: 100,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Open Form in pop up window',
        handler: function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Popup',
                width: 400,
                height: 100,
                autoShow: true,
                items: {
                    xtype: 'myForm'
                }
            })
        }
    }, {}, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Open Form View Port Center Region',
        handler: function () {
            let myForm = Ext.create('Test.view.MyForm')
            this.up('viewport').items.getAt(1).add(myForm);
        }
    }]

}, {
    region: 'center',
    id: 'mycenter',
    title: 'Center Region',
    items: [{
        html: ''
    }]
}]
})
```

app/view/MyForm

```
Ext.define('Test.view.MyForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'myForm',
width: 400,
height: 200,
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'mtfield',
    fieldLabel: 'TextField'
}]
})
```

Comment: You can define this in you controller

Comment: Thanks! But i have some problemes. If I use function inside Main i will face to  "Unrecognized class name / alias: Ext.window.Window" . If I give handler name inside Main and trying init handler button function i face to "No method named "nameOfHandler" on Ext.Button"..

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function handler function of the button, create object of the class related to it and call "show" method to add it viewport.

```
onButtonClickRenterId: function() {
    /* place for form calling by button function */
   var form = Ext.create('<class name defined in RenterData.js>');
   form.show();
}
```